# current Bounds form google map with ng-map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, ng-map

I use this:ngmap.github.io and ionic framework.

I try get current position daynamicly like this js code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function(){
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
 //returns an object with the NorthEast and SouthWest LatLng points of the bounds

});
```

how can I convert this code to angularjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps?files=1):

`NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {...})` is used to to get a map instance.

**Example**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngMap']);
app.controller('mapcntrl', function (NgMap, $scope) {

    NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
        console.log(map.getBounds().toString());
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="mapcntrl">
    <ng-map center="[-26.1367035,124.2706638]" zoom="5"></ng-map>
</div>
```